# example of nsnotification triggering an action when a message comes in with the subject line "WoodViolins"

Tags: objective-c, addressbook, message

Can someone show an example of this in objective-c? I have the addressbook framework and mail core to get the inbox. I don't know how to have it keep checking for new messages and notify when a message comes in with a specific subject.

Elijah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MailCore can not send you automatic notifications when things change. Using this framework, you'll have to periodically ping the server. Create a NSTimer:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(refresh:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

E.g. add a property for the last seen message count: `@property NSUInteger lastMessageCount;` Then write the polling method:

```
- (void)refresh:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
  // given a CTCoreFolder *folder
  NSUInteger count = [folder totalMessageCount];
  if (count != self.lastMessageCount)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FolderUpdated" object:folder];
  self.lastMessageCount = count;
}
```

You can now observe that notification and be informed on every folder change. Should be quite easy for you to adjust it to your needs now...

Comment: by iterating through all messages and checking their subjects. get them using `-messageObjectsFromIndex:toIndex:` and then iterate, checking each subject. You might also wan to check out `messageListWithFetchAttributes:`, maybe that applies filters directly on the server...

Comment: `NSSet *msgs = [folder messageObjectsFromIndex:0 toIndex:[folder totalMessageCount]-1]; for (CTMessage *msg in msgs) { if ([[msg subject] isEqual: @"hi"]) { ... } }`